# How to join tables to create a new shapefile in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, attribute-table, geocoding, attribute-joins

I'm unsure how to join a table and reference shapefile in order to create a new shapefile. I'm using ArcMap. I made a simplified version example below.

I have a shapefile of points (locations where an indvidual can reside). The points have a unique ID. The points don't have a specified lat/long. I also have a table of individuals. Each individual has a has residence information, in the same form as the point ID. More than one individual can be found at the same point.

I want to create a point shapefile that shows every individual's residence. I know that some of the points will overlap.

[image]

I thought I would have to use the "Add Join" tool, but when I used it, it didn't create a shapefile. Is there some special join tool that will create a new shapefile/table that will hold the point data and the individual data?

I don't know much about geocoding, but would it be useful in this situation? Any other thoughts would be a huge help?

Comment: Add Join is temporary, to preserve "Add Join" just save the Shapefile to another Shapefile. Right-click the layer, Data, Export Data. Or use "Join Field" which is permanent.

Comment: a) If I understand your question correctly, the values of RESIDENCE and ID match, however there may be more than one match between the two?  In which case you're in a one to many join, which doesn't work well as a Join. You can try to add a relationship instead.  b) What happened when you tried the add join? Are you able to see any names on the Attribute table?

Comment: I think this one to many join would work: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177510/104011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Make Query Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm) tool. Despite the name, it will create feature classes too!

You'll use it like this, in this case the table is named 'tbl' and the point feature class is 'pnts':

[image: Make Query Table]

A few important things:

- The points layer must be first under 'input tables.' This is what causes the output to be a feature class
- The expression builder will automatically add double quotes (") to the field names. You'll get an error if you don't remove them.
- This only creates a layer. You'll want to export the data out to save it permanently.
- Also, I see you are using shapefiles. I'm not sure if this will work on shapefiles directly; if not you may have to import them into a FGDB.