# How to make an ArcGIS Pro one-to-many table join?

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, one-to-many

From what I have been able to find in the ArcGIS Pro documentation via Google search for one-to-many table joins the only method other than using python (which I am not great at) would be the Query Table tool.

When I use the Query Table tool the output generates a temporary polygon feature class but whenever I try and view the attribute table it ends up with a spinning circle of doom and never loads. There is no error code associated so I'm not sure how to hunt down the problem.

Does anyone know how I might trouble-shoot this issue or if there is another way to do a one-to-many join in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Is this a situation where you could just switch the join direction (many-to-one)? If not you could export your data to a database, if you have one available, and use that to perform the join (Access would work for this)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the Query Table never seemed to work for me. It seemingly never went beyond a 2% completion even after I cleaned up the data to reduce the number of columns and/or rows. What I was able to find, however, was a round-about method which appears to work even though in the onset it doesn't (weird, right?).

[Here is the link to that round-about method I used](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177506/one-to-many-joins-on-a-feature-class-to-a-table)

While the above link seemingly solved my problem it didn't utilize the known ArcGIS Pro one-to-many options, so, to keep with the spirit of the original question, if anyone else could answer on it, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping both the data used for a join in the same geodatabase and using the Add join tool, we can create a one-to-many join in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The [Add Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm) tool can create one-to-many joins, but what the documentation doesn't say is that the layers must be stored in the same geodatabase.

I recommend creating a new geodatabase in your project folder, then importing the files you want to join into the geodatabase. Now when you use the join tool, if you click validate join, the output prompt should confirm that the join is one to many.